# Numbering of the subfigures are not centered with the figure in LATEX

Tags: latex, centering, caption, subfigure

The numbering (a,b,c) in the subfigures is a little off-center with the subfigures. I keep \caption inside the subfigure section empty because I do not want any captions but if I remove it, the numbering will go away. Is there any way to keep the numbering and make it centers with subfigures?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Paper/results.PNG}
\caption{} \label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Paper/results.PNG}
\caption{} \label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Paper/results.PNG}
\caption{} \label{fig3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figures}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image: I get this output]

Comment: Just like yesterday, your code does not compile! Please test your [mre] before you post a question!

Comment: Even if fixing all the errors, your code would not produce three subfigures in a row for the very same reason explained to you yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but your code still does not compile. Did you test it?

Comment: Hint: the packages are at the wrong place

Comment: Hi, sorry for that I think now it is compiling

Comment: No, `\begin{document}` is still at the wrong place. You must test your code before posting!

Comment: got it, I tested it

Comment: Two possible causes: a) your manually guessed scalling factor probably does not match the available space. Try with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}` instead. Your figures might have asymmetrical margins, we would need to see the actual pngs to diagnose this

Comment: pngs are a little asymmetrical since there is a label on the left side of the plot. I just want to know whether there is a way to manually adjust the numbering position since it is impossible to make the pngs symmetrical.

Comment: Don't try to adjust the numbering position. That's the part that is correct. The position of the images is the faulty part. I bet your images are simply to big and go into the margin. Warnings in the log file should tell you about overfull boxes.

Comment: The numbering (a,b,c) in the subfigures are not off-center with the subfigures. The real problem is that your image is composed not only by the plot but also the labels of the axes. If you consider the whole image the caption is perfectly centered.